# How to convert plain text to SHA-256 hash in Netezza?

Tags: hash, sha256, netezza, password-encryption

Can anyone please help me with some sql query where I can convert plain text to SHA-256 hash in Netezza..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_hash.html) show that this is simply calling the `hash` function with the second argument equal to 2.

```
select hash('string', 2)
```

But I'm presuming you'd like it in hexadecimal format, so wrap it in `rawtohex`.

```
select rawtohex(hash('string', 2))
```

Comment: We should note that these functions are part of the IBM Netezza SQL Extensions toolkit, which is included with Netezza, but may need to be installed or otherwise enabled for your environment.